# automount exfat permissions

Tags: mount, permissions, automount, exfat

When automounting an exFat USB, how do I define directory permissions and mount options?

I have a system (ubuntu 14.04.5) that is shared between multiple users, but only one (UID=1000) can attach USB's to the system.

All users share the same group (GID=1000).

When user 1000 copies files from vfat to a shared ext4 disk it copies the file with the same permissions in the vfat usb (0644), but when copying from the exfat usb, the permissions are (0700) so after a copy is made only UID=1000 can access the files in the shared disk.

I've been trying to change mount options without luck udisk2 does not let do that or if there is a way, it's unknown to me.

How can I ask gfvs->udisks2 to mount exfat partitions with umask=0770 ?
udisks2 creates a mount point before mounting, but I can not change the permissions udisks2 sets on such mount point, again 0700.

Does anyone know how to customice a little the mount directory and mount process so I can share content copied from the exfat usb ?

I've tryed to change udev rules (80-udisks2.rules) with
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs|exfat|fuseblk", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,umask=000,allow_other"
without any luck, and I don't want to hard code this options on udisks2 sources.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks all